# How do I specify which variables are at which levels in a hierarchical linear model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

A reviewer has suggested I do a hierarchical linear model for a journal article, but none of the tutorials I could find online: (Example: [1](https://methodenlehre.github.io/intro-to-rstats/hierarchical-linear-models.html), [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/hierarchical-linear-modeling-a-step-by-step-guide-424b486ac6a3), [3](https://rpubs.com/angelayuan/HLM), [4](https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol08-1/p052/p052.pdf)...) were helpful.

I want to construct a hierarchical linear model that has multiple predictor variables on each level. I’m using the [lme4 library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) in R. I want to see if the number of science activities a child completes predicts their score on a science test while controlling for multiple student and classroom-level variables.

The outcome variable is children's score on a science test. Level 1 of the model is the number of science activities children completed (or whether they were in the control group). Level 2 is the student level; I have multiple student variables (e.g., age, race, gender). Level 3 is the classroom level; I also have multiple classroom variables (e.g., science programs teachers already use, years a teacher has been teaching, teacher’s undergraduate major).

The tutorials have me thinking that my model should look something like this:

```
model1 <- lmer(testscore ~ numsciactivities + (1 | participant) + (1 | classroom), REML = FALSE, data = mydata)
```

However, that model doesn’t control for any student or classroom variables. So if I were to try doing that, I would expect my model to look something like this:

```
model2 <- lmer(testscore ~ numsciactivities + age + race_white + race_black + race_asian + gender + (1 | sciprogram) + yrsteaching + (1 | teachermajor), REML = FALSE, data = mydata)
```

or maybe this:

```
model3 <- lmer(testscore ~ numsciactivities + (1 + age + race_white + race_black + race_asian + gender | participant) + (1 + sciprogram + yrsteaching + teachermajor | classroom), REML=FALSE, data=mydata)
```

The problem is that I’m not seeing anywhere where levels 1, 2, and 3 of the model are explicitly specified. How do I correctly specify which variables are at which levels, or do I not need to do so? Also, could I use the control group as the reference category of numsciactivities?

Comment: "Also, could I use the control group as the reference category of numsciactivities?" Isn't number of activities a numeric variable?

Comment: It's better to say more about how your data is structured. How many classrooms? How many students per classroom? Is there any missing data? ... Provide as much detail as possible. The best option is to share your data, or simulated data that preserved the structure and important aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes on your model:

1. You have coded race multiple times as variable. Don't. It makes far more sense to code it as one variable, `Race`, then it does to code it as several dichotomous variables.
2. Participants are technically nested within classrooms in this setting. So your random effects should at minimum look something like `(1|classroom/participant)`. There is also [this thread on random effects structures for nested effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448508/3-level-random-intercept-at-level-2-random-slope-and-random-intercept-at-l). I also advise looking at the syntax page of the original `lme4` package article on how to specify the model.
3. You can include as many random slope terms as you want, but keep in mind that the more random effects parameters you include, the harder it will be to converge. See [this article on the subject.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04967.pdf).
4. If you need good tutorials on HLM, I suggest a few other articles below as citations. I think they are pretty straight forward and helpful in ways that most HLM books and articles are not.

Citations:

- [Brown, 2021](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/epub/10.1177/2515245920960351)
- [Harrison et al., 2018](https://peerj.com/articles/4794/)
- [Meteyard & Davies, 2020](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2020-22600-001)

### Edit

By the way, I looked through the `lmer` article by Bates and this is the breakdown if you want to look. The `g1` here would be your classroom and the `g2` would be the participant:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the notation (1|A/B) mean that B is nested within A? So (1|classroom/participant)?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. Let me amend that.

Comment: 1) I'm assuming it would be okay to treat race as a factor here, if it is a single variable?
2) and 3) This makes sense, but how could I properly control for each of the student and classroom-level predictor variables? Do they have to be added as random slope terms (1 + age + race + gender + sciprogram + yrsteaching + teachermajor | classroom/participant) or is there another way they can be added to the model to minimize issues with convergence?

Comment: 1) Im not entirely sure what you mean by "as a factor here." If you mean as a random effect, I would say no, as it is more appropriate as a fixed effect in my opinion (it isn't random noise, it likely has predictive value in your model. But as a fixed effect race can be used as a single categorical variable, which when run in a regression will have an output that shows differences between each race. 2) and 3) You can add them for sure, just keep in mind that the more parameters you have the harder it is for the model to converge. Lmer models are very sensitive to complexity.

Comment: I also don't know if you can add level 1 and level 2 random effects into the same intercept term. You may need to consult with somebody on that decision, but I believe you would need to change the random effects in your model a bit to make that work. For example perhaps: `(1 + age + race + gender + sciprogram  | participant) + (1 + yrsteaching + teachermajor | classroom) + (1 | classroom:participant)`

Comment: @dipetkov may have some useful comments on this.

Comment: You don't specify the hierarchy levels explicitly with `lme4`. What you need to think about instead is what random structure is appropriate for your data: are random intercepts for children and classes enough or do you want to include some random slopes as well. In any case, I suspect that you won't be able to estimate so many random effects.

Comment: Why not start with: `Y ~ [all covariates as fixed effects] + (1|classroom/participant)`? That is the most straightforward generalization from a model that treats all data points as independent to a model that takes into account the correlations between data points from the same class/student.

Comment: I also recommend "Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models" by Gelman & Hill, esp. chapters 12 and 13. Keep in mind though that this textbook has a strong focus on Bayesian analysis, since that works particularly well for hierarchical models.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Yes, I would be using race as a fixed effect. I would say as.factor(race) in the model (that's what I meant by treating it as a factor). I'm also not sure I understand this: `(1 + age + race + gender + sciprogram  | participant) + (1 + yrsteaching + teachermajor | classroom) + (1 | classroom:participant)` Would this treat every variable as a random effect?

Comment: @dipetkov I started with `Y ~ [all covariates as fixed effects] + (1|classroom/participant)`  for simplicity. I ran into this error: `Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: participant:classroom)`. After looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713228/lmer-error-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-observations), I don't understand why i'm getting the error because there is more than one student per classroom...

Comment: @dipetkov Also, I am not sure what issues would arise if I added random slopes. I also don't expect the relation between the explanatory and response variable to differ significantly based on each covariate, but I am new to this kind of analysis.

Comment: Issues did arise, didn't they? Models with many random effects have to estimate many parameters. The error message that you get really says that you don't have enough observations to estimate the random parameters you've specified.